# What is the best way to write into a byte variable at a predefined position?

Tags: solidity, bytes, access

According to the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html?highlight=string) one can access the byte at position k in for example a Bytes16 variable source with the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract example {

 Bytes16 source=0xa9c40ddcb43ebbc83add97b8f9f361f1;

 function returnByte(uint k) returns (bytes1 a) {
    a = source[k];
    return a;       
 }

}
```

However, as stated in the documentation, this only works for **read access**. What is the best way to **write** at a defined position k into the Bytes16 source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with a bit of bit trickery (at the cost of 450 gas):

```
function setByte(bytes16 x, uint8 i, byte b)  returns (bytes16) {
    bytes16 mask = bytes16(0xff) << i*8;
    return (x & ~mask) | (bytes16(b) >> (15-i)*8);
}
```

Comment: How to do this to only get the certain position without change, let's say `getByte(bytes 16, uint8 i) returns (bytes2)`

Comment: @EduardoPereira `return bytes2(x >> i*8);`